# FullSimplify to minimum number of terms according to assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a large expression that I want to simplify according to some conditions, which FullSimplify doesn't seem to take into account.

For example, let's say I have:

```
expr = p[3].k[2] + p[3].k[4];
Cond = Sum[p[3].k[j], {j, {1, 2, 4}}];
FullSimplify[expr, Assumptions -> Cond == 0]
```

The result is `p[3].k[2] + p[3].k[4]` - unchanged. However, I would like this to be `-p[3].k[1]` which seems obviously simpler.

What is interesting, is that the `expr = p[3].k[1] + p[3].k[2]` does simplify correctly, but I don't understand why (since `Plus[]` is Orderless)

Note: I need to find out how to do this in general - I know I could use replacement rules or something but in reality my condition might be a large sum applied to many arbitrary terms. I don't want to have to do it by hand each time if avoidable. Thanks!

Comment: Not even this simplifies: `Simplify[p[3].k[2] + p[3].k[4], p[3].k[2] + p[3].k[4] == -p[3].k[1]]`.

Comment: It could be helpful to add the key word dot product in the title since other members might be searching for a similar problem.

Comment: xAct is a good Mathematica library for tensor algebra. Maybe it has a function that helps. You can check the xact website for documentation